Parents thinking about divorcing
before I begin, for a bit of context my parents have not been on their best terms a month or two before the Christmas holidays.
Over the Christmas break, my mum isolated herself from my dad,myself and my 15 year old sister for a period of 3 days by sitting in her room, this has happened for majority of my life. Throughout today 28/12/2024 my mum was out and about and we did manage to go out as a family in town and when we came home my parents began arguing. The main 2 reasons are that my dad doesn't really make time for us lot because he said he'll come home late, he is busy or that he is working on Saturdays and the second one is because me,my sister and dad go to church on Sundays, but for the rest of the day he sleeps and whenever my mum suggests to go out somewhere he says ' we don't have the money' or ' I'm tired I don't want to' both of these have been said way too many times since October.
Then as you can imagine, they were both shouting at each other. As both my parents know how to cook food, my dad says to my mum 'if I ever leave back to Romania YOU make sure you cook for the kids', my mum is the one who mainly cooks like she did tonight. Oh and yes we are
a Romanian family.
Over dinner my mum mentioned that dad said 'If you don't like it here you can leave' and of course I began to tear up but not fully cry. My sister mentioned that they can go to a marriage counsellor, my mum agreed but due to how fucking arrogant my dad said ' no you are the one who is stubborn and big headed and you are the one who needs therapy'.
All my life I've had my parents around me and I do not want this to change anytime soon. I've been crying most nights for a while, not just nights but you get me. I am scared of what my dad will decide to do and I literally do not want to pick sides but I really badly want to call him out for numerous reasons but I don't want to as I'll get yelled at.
As I've been crying typing this up, could anyone please give me some advice on how to keep my parents together and not want them to separate anytime soon please!!!
P.S- I apologise for waffling but I hope you get the idea.

I know it’s tough, but in the end, a separation or divorce is neither your fault nor anything that would be in your power to prevent. It’s about two adults and their relationship. We sadly get questions like yours occasionally, which is why I’m closing this as duplicate. Please follow the links and read through the answers there. Even if the specific details are different in each family, the answers remain valid. Take care!
